# How to use a feed from Azure Kinect in multiple applications?

Tags: python, c++, azure, kinect-sdk, azurekinect

I have Azure Kinect and I am currently using PyK4a wrapper for python and Azure Kinect SDK for C++ application. I want to use feed from my Kinect in two applications at the same time. Is it possible to do this in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to create a new application that reads the feed from the Kinect. This new application would then forward the feed to your two applications.